# Make popup window close when releasing mouse button on an item on the fly

Tags: delphi, contextmenu

When clicking on a button I open a popup menu, e.g. using popupMenu.popup().
To select an item I must first release the mouse button and then click on a menu item to execute it.

This is "normal", but what I want is the behavior that I won't have to do an extra click on the menu item. I would like to be able to click on the button, move over a menu item (still holding the button) and execute it immediately after releasing the mouse button.
This is similar to how cascaded sub menus work.

I tried the way using TrackPopupMenu to hook into the messages and execute the item when the button is released. This works, but...
When using images in the popup menu (either bitmap or imagelist items) together with TrackPopupMenu then the menu does not show any entry. Every entry is some pixels wide and empty. You can use them blindly, so they work somehow but the drawing is not done correctly.

I'm using Delphi XE2 Pro.

I also tried to find general articles to hook into menu messages but did not find anything that works without using TrackPopupMenu. Maybe there is a way to have TrackPopupMenu displaying menus with images?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are routing menu messages to the wrong window procedure, you are passing the handle of your form to `TrackPopupMenu` (you should post your code, then there would be no need to *guess* what you're doing wrong. And you'd probably receive a much quicker reply).

Forms have menu support for window menus. When a form window procedure receives a, say `WM_DRAWITEM`, it only draws the item if it belongs to the window menu. For popup menus, VCL uses a utility window which is accessible through the global `PopupList`. See below example.

```
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  Pt := Button1.ClientToScreen(Point(0, Button1.Height));
  TrackPopupMenu(PopupMenu1.Handle, TPM_LEFTBUTTON, Pt.X, Pt.Y, 0,
      PopupList.Window, nil);
```

Comment: Excellent! That was the mistake. And to make me feel even more stupid: As soon as you use TrackPopupMenu as with your example it behaves exactly the way I want it without doing any extra message handling. It opens the popup and as soon as I release the button on a menu item it immediately executes it.

Thank you very much!